# Jaeger-query and Jaeger-collector pods in CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, jaeger

I am trying to deploy the Jaeger Helm chart with Azure Cosmos DB acting as the Cassandra Storage Backend. I have set up the CosmosDB and created a values file as below:

```
storage:
  type: cassandra
  cassandra:
    host: xxxxxxx.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com
    port: 10350
    user: xxxxxx
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    tls:
      enabled: false
      secretName: cassandra-tls-secret

provisionDataStore:
  cassandra: false
```

The command that I am using to deploy jaeger with the values file is:

```
helm install jaeger jaegertracing/jaeger -n <my-namespace> -f values.yml
```

However, on checking the pods, the collector and the query are in CrashLoopBackOff

[image]

Both the containers on running the describe command complain:

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

I am not sure what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide all the YAML file that you used?

Comment: Hi Charles, I used the public repo jaegertracing/jaeger - https://github.com/jaegertracing/helm-charts/tree/master/charts

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it seems you miss setting the TLS for Cassandra Storage in Azure Cosmos DB. When you use the Cassandra client to connect the Cassandra Storage in Azure Cosmos DB, it will give out the time out error, but if you enable the SSL, the connection works well. So I think you can try to enable the TLS for Cassandra in your values.yaml following the steps in the Github which provided.

Comment: How do you enable the TLS for cassandra. I looked that up but could not find the certificate for the same.

Comment: @AkashMasand You need to enable the TLS following the steps [here](https://github.com/jaegertracing/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/jaeger#installing-the-chart-using-an-existing-cassandra-cluster-with-tls). The certificates should be created yourself.

Comment: As per the link you shared, I am assuming the CA cert would be the BaltimoreCybertrustroot certificate. When you refer to the certificates being created by me, do you mean the client key and the certificate should be created by me?

Comment: @AkashMasand Yeah, I think so. And you can try to use the client to connect the Cassandra Storage in Azure Cosmos DB as I said in the answer. Or connect from your local machine to test.

Comment: @AkashMasand Any more updates? Do you solve the problem with my answer? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: Hi Charles, unfortunately no. I am not sure how to get the baltimore cybertrust root certificate in for jaeger.